# How to locate a server name in sql server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server

How would I go about finding my server name on sql 2014, I've recently downloaded SQL Server 2014 Express CTP2 (x64) - (English).

Answer (score 0):

Just run:

```
SELECT @@SERVERNAME AS 'Server Name'
```

in Sql Server.

Answer (score 0):

If we're talking about getting the *current* server name via T-SQL, run `SELECT @@servername`.

However, if we're talking about figuring out what servers are installed on the local machine, go into the Sql Server Configuration Manager and view the services. Otherwise, since I'm not sure that always gets installed, you can just go to Services and look for anything with SQL in the name. I believe they're labelled `SQL Server (<servername>)`. You could also just go into SSMS and choose "Browse for More" in the server-picking dropdown. Then under local servers yours should be listed.